# react native: why it's loosing part of the props levels on navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

here is a log of the `props` I receive in a component:

```
{"infos": {
        "opening": "10:00:00",
        "closing": "03:50:00",
        "id": "1046",
        "name": "Le QG",
        "description": null,
        "isreferenced": false,
        "ischecked": false,        
        "funnyhour": {
            "id": "3",
            "isreferenced": true,
            "ischecked": false,
            "createdby": "1",
            "updatedby": "1",
            "createdAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z"
        }
    },
    "rights": false}
```

then I navigate without modifying the props:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('editFunny', props) || setModal()}></TouchableOpacity>
```

and when I log again the same props on the next page I loose a complete level (infos and rights):

```
{
    "navigation": {},
    "route": {
        "key": "editSunny-Qa7StMJIoiKUcklbwhIDh",
        "name": "editSunny",
        "params": {
            "opening": "10:00:00",
            "closing": "03:50:00",
            "id": "1046",
            "name": "Le QG",
            "description": null,
            "isreferenced": false,
            "ischecked": false,        
            "funnyhour": {
                "id": "3",
                "isreferenced": true,
                "ischecked": false,
                "createdby": "1",
                "updatedby": "1",
                "createdAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z"
            }
     }
}
```

Why ?
Plus it was working normally at the begining of the day, what could I have changed for this new behaviour? I am pulling my hair ! help

Comment: We need to see more of the context here. Can you post the component(s) including where you are doing the logging?

Answer (score 0):

In the next page you should access the props using `route.params` -

```
const EditFunny = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const props = route.params;
  console.log('props', props);
  .....
  .....
}
```

console log

```
props {"infos": {"closing": "03:50:00", "description": null, "funnyhour": {"createdAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z", "createdby": "1", "id": "3", "ischecked": false, "isreferenced": true, "updatedAt": "2022-08-11T20:31:41.854Z", "updatedby": "1"}, "id": "1046", "ischecked": false, "isreferenced": false, "name": "Le QG", "opening": "10:00:00"}, "rights": false}
```

EDIT:
With `useContext` you can get route params like this -

```
import { NavigationContext, NavigationRouteContext } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);
const route = React.useContext(NavigationRouteContext);
const props = route.params;
console.log('props', props);
```

Comment: sorry i dint mention but i am using :
const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);